# How to extract the data from IBMKeyword in UiPath?

Tags: ibm-watson, uipath

I am experimenting with the IBM Watson NLU’s Text Analysis package in UiPath with a simple text. I am able to extract the KeyValue pair information for Categories, Concept, and Sentiments using .ToString() . However, I am having trouble in figuring out how to extract information for Keywords, Entity both are of type IBMKeyword, IBMEntity

A simple .ToString() method in the message box gives something that's not helping or I don't know how to use it.

[image: Message box of keyWords.ToString()]

Below is the screenshot of my UiPath Studio:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Try this]

Try this. Since the variable has multiple keywords, it cannot be printed in a single message box without a loop

Comment: Just tried that.. Didn't work. The output is the same. Even when I tried item.ToString it just displays "UiPath.Cognitive.Text.Analysis.IBMKeyword" twice